What is the difference between the .NET Minimal API and .NET AOT and how does it relate to each other if they are?
I have searched on the Internet, and I couldn't find a concrete explanation regarding this.
I have used the Minimal API before, and when I am using the .NET AOT, the project source code seems different except for the endpoints are still in the Program.cs file.

Different but can be used together.
Minimal API has to do with streamlining HTTP calls and AOT creates machine code.
AOT can take the Minimal API code along with the rest of the app/DLL and create machine code.

Native AOT for ASP.NET Core was added with .NET 8 - check out the corresponding section of the What's new in ASP.NET Core 8.0 doc.
ASP.NET Core support for Native AOT doc covers the feature in more detail. First of all you should notice Minimal APIs are supported partially (and MVC is not supported at all):



Feature
Fully Supported
Partially Supported
Not Supported




gRPC
✔️Fully supported




Minimal APIs

✔️Partially supported



MVC


❌Not supported


Blazor Server


❌Not supported


SignalR


❌Not supported


JWT Authentication
✔️Fully supported




Other Authentication


❌Not supported


CORS
✔️Fully supported




...
...
...
...



The main difference in the template itself comes from the fact that reflection APIs are not supported in the Native AOT so you need to switch to source generation for System.Text.Json (see the Minimal APIs and JSON payloads section of the docs too):

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
options.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.Insert(0, AppJsonSerializerContext.Default);
});

[JsonSerializable(typeof(Todo[]))]
internal partial class AppJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext
{

}

Without this added code, System.Text.Json uses reflection to serialize and deserialize JSON. Reflection isn't supported in Native AOT.

The second noticable difference is usage of CreateSlimBuilder method instead of CreateBuilder. For more details see the CreateSlimBuilder vs CreateBuilder section of the docs.
